# Inheriting from an instance of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two classes as follows in a header file

```
template<size_t N>
class Parent{
    protected:
    char array[N];
    size_t i;
    public:
    virtual void operator()(int i);
};

template<size_t N>
void Parent<N>::operator()(int i){
    this->i = i;
}

class Child: public Parent<16>{
    public:
    virtual void operator()();
};
```

Child has operator()() defined elsewhere in a cpp file. Whenever I include this header file from another cpp file I can access operator()() but operator()(int) is not even defined. Why is this? I thought since I inherit from a specific instance of Parent, all the methods of it should be instanced as well and available.

Comment: Is that actual code? You have a function with no return type.

Comment: Show the exact code you're using (or a narrowed down example of the same thing) and the compiler error.

Comment: You could help people by indenting your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the errors in your code, this is an example of *hiding*: Your derived class declares a function of the same name *but with different signature* as a base class. Thus the base function is *hidden*:

```
class A { virtual void foo(); };

class B : public A { virtual void foo(int); /* hides A::foo() ! */ };
```

Inheritance only affects functions that have the same signature (with some mild exceptions).

Your base class function is declared as `void Parent<N>::operator()(int)`, while in your derived class you declare `void Child::operator()()`.

In C++11 you can explicitly say `virtual void foo(int) override` to trigger a compiler error if the function isn't overriding anything.

If you intentionally want to define a new function with the same name as an existing one but with different signature, and not overriding the base function, then you can make the base function visible with a `using` directive:

```
class C : public A
{
  using A::foo();
  void foo(int);
};  // now have both C::foo(int) and C::foo()
```

Comment: Add information on making hidden functions visible with `using`.

Comment: @K-ballo: OK, done. I wasn't sure if the OP was looking for that, but it's actually quite likely.

Comment: Thank you. I had posted the example in a fury before I went to sleep. I appreciate the help. I think I have ran into the issue once before, but cannot seem to commit this use of the 'using' operator to my knowledge of c++.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Parent's operator() hides the Child's operator() (they have different signatures). How come you are not getting warnings when you compile your code?

This is how it should be :

```
class Child: public Parent<16>{
  public:
    using Parent<16>::operator();
    virtual void operator()();
};
```